# Can "Question (Revised )" be fixed?

Tags: bug, status-completed, review

In the latest version of the reopen queue, the first tab currently states "Question (Revised )" with a space preceding the closing bracket.

[image: (Revised )]

This is a nice easy one, can it be fixed please?

Comment: @Cole  http://cdn.memegenerator.net/instances/400x/21182250.jpg

Comment: Can "Question (Revised )" be revised    ?

Comment: of course, fix incoming...

Comment: +1 for using please!

Comment: I will personally come to your house and bludgeon you to death with a giant space. — [Jeff Atwood](http://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/1165936105)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed in build 2013.8.6.1313 (meta) / 2013.8.6.920 (sites )